# Issue with buttons not functioning after start of program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new and learning python 3.6 and I've almost completed my first code project. After doing an exhaustive search to resolve my problem I have not been able to find the answer to what I am sure is a simple oversight.

Program premise:
A user enters a URL and also clicks in a checkbox for the time frame to call the url. The user then clicks the start button and the program begins to open the url in a timeloop according to the checkbox(time) selected.
This is working fine... however once the program has started the buttons are no longer active and do not work, they are not able to be clicked.
I have used tkinter for the gui.

I am trying to keep 2 buttons active for the user. The Quit button, which quits the function of the program and the Exit button that exits and closes the program completely.

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Current sleep() code used:

```
def execute():
execute = urllib.request.urlopen(url.get()))

def Time():
if CheckVar1.get() and url.get():
timeloop = True
Sec = 0
Min = 0
timeLoop = A
while timeLoop:
    Sec += 1
    execute()
    time.sleep(300)
```

I hope this helps make my question a little easier to follow.
I believe that I might need to find another way to do what this is doing so that the loop allows the other parts of the program (buttons), to remain active so a user can Quit or Exit the program once it is running.
Note: CheckVar1.get() is to verify if the checkbox has been selected for that time frame, there are 8 different time settings being used.

Comment: How are people supposed to know, what's wrong with your code, if you don't post it here? [Please edit your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You want to do the downloading in a background thread.

Comment: I think your timeloop does not let the tkinter mainloop make its job.

Comment: The program is using urllib.request.urlopen(url.get())
Everything work as it's supposed to other then the buttons to quit the loop function when running or exit and close the program.
The Exit and Quit buttons work properly prior to executing the call to the loop using the start button. Only after executing the program function buttons become inactive.

Comment: @progmatico - I am not sure if I understand what you have said completely.
The program is working using the timeloop and it is calling the site url as scheduled using the timeloop but once it is running the buttons become inactive and not able to be used.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that illustrates the problem. We can't debug code that we can't see.

Comment: What is your timeloop, are you sleeping your code with sleep() or something? That will freeze the gui because will stop tkinter from getting events from its own event mainloop

Comment: @Johnny's comment is important if you block the gui because the download takes some time. Show us your precious code if you can. We love code :)

Comment: @progmatico, Yes it is  using sleep() to allow it to be run in set times. I was not are that it would prevent other functions to be active while it is running that loop. Can you suggest an alternative way to have it iterate at specific time frames?

Answer (score 0):

Your code indentation is wrong and maybe there are  other issues too, but as your approach is essentially wrong, here is an example of how to call a fuction after some time in tkinter, without blocking the UI. This can be used as a kind of background processing, and it's simple:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk


def some_action():
    # do what you want
    # ...
    print('Hi! Getting my urls here...')
    # but don't block with sleeps or infinite loops,
    # and then
    next_check = get_your_check_interval() # somehow calculate or
                                           # retrieve this from
                                           # your vars or widgets,
                                           # using seconds
    # register for the next call of some_action
    root.after(next_check*1000, some_action)

def get_your_check_interval():
    return 3 # just using 3 seconds now...

root = Tk()

start_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Start', command=some_action)
quit_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=quit)


start_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
quit_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

As you see the buttons remain responsive and you can quit the application.
So I think you can solve your problem with the same technique.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the assistance and I will go over this piece this evening when I arrive home.
Thank you once again for the guidance and help.