# How do I get a label to update after function calls within a TopLevel window?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm trying to build a toplevel window within python that has a single label within it called "text". It's textvariable is called "v". As you can see, there are 3 function calls within dialogueBox(). What I want the program to do is have the label "text" display the phrase "Event one", wait one second, display the phrase "Event two", wait one second, and then display the phrase "Event three". Instead of doing this, the top level window is opened displaying only "Event three".

I suspect that this is a lambda issue but I'm still not sure how to use it in Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import*
import time

def event1():
    v.set("Event one")


def event2():
    v.set("Event two")

def event3():
    v.set("Event three")



def dialogueBox():
    top = Toplevel()
    global v
    top.minsize(400,0)
    top.maxsize(700,300)
    top.title("Toplevel test")
    v = StringVar()
    text = Label(top,textvariable = v)
    text.pack()

    event1()
    time.sleep(1)
    event2()
    time.sleep(1)
    event3()

root = Tk()
email = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
title = Label(root,text="Root window",font = 11)
title.pack()
label1 = Label(root,text = "Username")
label1.pack()
field1 = Entry(root,textvariable = email)
field1.pack()
label2 = Label(root,text = "Password")
label2.pack()
field2 = Entry(root,show = "*",textvariable = password)
field2.pack()
button = Button(root,text = "Get data",command = dialogueBox)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the issue is the call to sleep. When the GUI sleeps, it can't update. Do some research on the tkinter method `after`.

Comment: right, same kind of trouble as in this question, see the `after` sample there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839120/issue-with-buttons-not-functioning-after-start-of-program/47875232?noredirect=1#comment82719410_47875232

Comment: I've tried using the after method but it seems to give me the same problem.

Comment: in `event1()` use `root.after(1000, event2)` and it will run `event2` one second after `event1` - and you have to remove `sleep`  and function `event2()`/`event3()` after `sleep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, but your best bet is using the `after()` method.

Here's your modified code, with comments added:

```
from tkinter import*
import time

def event1():
    v.set("Event one")
    root.after(1000, event2) # NEW


def event2():
    v.set("Event two")
    root.after(1000, event3) # NEW

def event3():
    v.set("Event three")



def dialogueBox():
    top = Toplevel()
    global v
    top.minsize(400,0)
    top.maxsize(700,300)
    top.title("Toplevel test")
    v = StringVar()
    text = Label(top,textvariable = v)
    text.pack()

    event1()
    #time.sleep(1)
    #event2()
    #time.sleep(1)
    #event3()

root = Tk()
email = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
title = Label(root,text="Root window",font = 11)
title.pack()
label1 = Label(root,text = "Username")
label1.pack()
field1 = Entry(root,textvariable = email)
field1.pack()
label2 = Label(root,text = "Password")
label2.pack()
field2 = Entry(root,show = "*",textvariable = password)
field2.pack()
button = Button(root,text = "Get data",command = dialogueBox)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The only real change is employing the `after` method from `event1()` to call `event2()`, and from `event2()` to call `event3()`.  With these `after()` calls, the last 4 lines in your `dialogueBox()` go away.

What is happening?  Tkinter is a GUI, event-driven system. It doesn't like sitting there and waiting for anything. While you're sleeping, resources are wasted, and the GUI cannot refresh and update itself. By employing the `after()` method, the GUI can continue doing what it does best: waiting for events and input.  The `after()` method schedules an event to occur later on. When that time comes, the event gets processed.  The first arg to `after()` is the time delay in ms (milliseconds). The second arg is a function name, to be called after the designated time delay.

Now, I said that `after()` is your best bet, but there is another way to do this, albeit less "polite."  You could add `.update()` method calls to your `dialogueBox()`, as follows:

```
def dialogueBox():
    top = Toplevel()
    global v
    top.minsize(400,0)
    top.maxsize(700,300)
    top.title("Toplevel test")
    v = StringVar()
    text = Label(top,textvariable = v)
    text.pack()

    event1()
    text.update()  # NEW -- RUDE!
    time.sleep(1)
    event2()
    text.update()  # NEW -- RUDE!
    time.sleep(1)
    event3()
```

The `.update()` calls rudely tell the GUI, "Stop everything you're doing and do this for me right now!"  This will also allow you to see the event1, event2, event3 messages. But the `after()` is really the better, proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In `event1()` use `root.after(1000, event2)` and it will run `event2` one second after `event1`

And you have to remove `sleep()`  and functions `event2()` `event3()`  from `dialog_box()`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def event1():
    v.set("Event one")
    root.after(1000, event2) # run event2 after 1000ms (1s)

def event2():
    v.set("Event two")
    root.after(1000, event3) # run event3 after 1000ms (1s)

def event3():
    v.set("Event three")
    root.after(1000, close_it) # run close_it after 1000ms (1s)

def close_it():
    top.destroy() # close TopLevel window

def dialogue_box():
    global v
    global top

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.minsize(400,0)
    top.maxsize(700,300)
    top.title("Toplevel test")

    v = tk.StringVar()
    text = tk.Label(top, textvariable=v)
    text.pack()

    event1() # run event1 at once

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

email = tk.StringVar()
password = tk.StringVar()

title = tk.Label(root, text="Root window", font=11)
title.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Username")
label1.pack()

field1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=email)
field1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Password")
label2.pack()

field2 = tk.Entry(root, show="*", textvariable=password)
field2.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Get data", command=dialogue_box)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi. Is there any advantage of importing tkinter as tk over just importing the entire module. I'm relatively new to this and I'm not too sure of python conventions for importing stuff.

Comment: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). `import *` is not prefered because you get all functions in the same `"name space"`. if you import other module which has class/method with the same name then you override first version and you don't have access to it. For example: `tkinter has `tkinter.Button` and `tkinter.ttk.Button` - if you import `tkinter` and `ttk` using `*` then you have access only to one of this buttons.

Comment: When I look in code and see `tk.Button` or `ttk.Button` then I know in which documentation I have to search more info. And I know that it is not class created by user `Button` so I don't have to search it in other files in user's project to get more info.

Comment: Saying `import tkinter` is much cleaner than saying `from tkinter import *` due to name space preservation, as described by furas. Saying `import tkinter as tk` is just as clean as `import tkinter`, but by "renaming" the module (giving it an alias), you can use a shorter name, which is quite common. Some imports are expected to be renamed by custom. For example, the standard to import numpy is `import numpy as np`. And pandas is typically imported as `import pandas as pd`.

Answer (score 0):

See demo of after here, also with itertools "show off"

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from itertools import cycle

label_iter = cycle(('Event One', 'Event Two', 'Event Three'))

def change_label():
    v.set(next(label_iter))
    root.after(1000, change_label)


def dialogueBox():
    top = Toplevel()
    global v
    top.minsize(400,0)
    top.maxsize(700,300)
    top.title("Toplevel test")
    v = StringVar()
    text = Label(top,textvariable = v)
    text.pack()

    root.after(1000, change_label)

root = Tk()
email = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
title = Label(root,text="Root window",font = 11)
title.pack()
label1 = Label(root,text = "Username")
label1.pack()
field1 = Entry(root,textvariable = email)
field1.pack()
label2 = Label(root,text = "Password")
label2.pack()
field2 = Entry(root,show = "*",textvariable = password)
field2.pack()
button = Button(root,text = "Get data",command = dialogueBox)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi. Although this program produces the result that I want, it doesn't call 3 separate functions, but iterates through a sequence of strings. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: You are welcome. But I am not making your program, I am just illustrating a concept or two for you.